# Can cheap Arduino Nano clones infect or damage my computer?

Tags: security, virus, clone, arduino, nano

I recently purchased several Arduino Nano v3 clones from a merchant on AliExpress. I got them for around $2.00 each. I'm aware of the possibility that they may arrive damaged or just not working.

However, a friend of mine raised a concern that they may infect or damage my computer when I attempt to program them. Is this is even possible? If so, what precautions can I take? Will burning a different bootloader help?

[Link to Arduino Nano Clones](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1665783181.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4a3b4c4dsKgvcj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not plug in devices you do not trust. Period.

There have been many hacks over the years involving autoplaying USB sticks so they could conceivably imitate a USB storage device and try to get your machine to run an executable.

Going a step further they could also appear to the operating system as a USB keyboard and spew keystrokes to manually run an executable from the internet or stored on the device.

In a more nefarious and damaging attack plugging in a USB device might access the [CPU directly via a debugging interface](https://thenextweb.com/security/2017/11/09/researchers-find-almost-every-computer-intel-skylake-cpu-can-owned-via-usb/) and directly inject exploit code without you ever knowing.

If you don't trust them, and don't know if the silicon itself hasn't been tampered with then there is nothing you can do that will make them trustworthy.

While the bootloader might be able to be reflashed, many devices such as that one might have a backup bootloader in the silicon itself that it falls back to if the flash based bootloader is corrupted. If that bootloader is altered at the silicon foundry then you've already lost.